# String literals not supported in stored procedure calls to DB2 for z/OS

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, mainframe, zos

I'm getting the error below when calling a simple SP from the Rational Application Developer Data Perspective when connecting to a DB2 DB instance running on z/OS. Also when calling from SQuirreL. Straight SQL queries run no problem. The query also works fine when called from my JAVA code.

`'Error: [ibm][db2][jcc][10243][10940] String literals not supported in 
    stored procedure calls to DB2 for z/OS'` 

Stored Proc is

`CREATE PROCEDURE testEM( IN id CHAR(12) )
    P1: BEGIN 
      .....
    END P1`

Works fine on a local DB2 instance, anybody any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, been doing some more investigation into this and I had the wrong driver locally. Upgrading to the DB2 v9.5 driver for the local connection settings solved the issue and calling SProcs with string literals is now working. Just in case anyone has the same issue in the future.